# SQL Найти сотрудника, который работал в отделе, местоположение которого совпадает с их адресом

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, postgresql

столкнулся с проблемой не могу написать запрос на SQL.
Проблема в том, что это  нужно написать с помощью вложенного подзапроса.
Есть у кого идеи?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня получилось с помощью Join, но я не представляю не могу найти правильный синтаксис. Буду рад помощи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Твоё решение правильное, но проще и грамотнее будет вот так

```
SELECT *
FROM emp
WHERE (emp.id,emp.address) IN (SELECT id_emp,location FROM departament)
```

Comment: Спасибо, это действительно выглядит намного лучше)

Answer (score 1):

Вот решение моей проблемы

```
SELECT *
FROM emp
WHERE emp.id IN (SELECT id_emp FROM departament)
and emp.address IN (SELECT location FROM departament)
```